# COPY INTO <table> in snowflake throws table does not exist

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to copy data to snowflake from local and I am getting

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001757 (42601): SQL compilation error:
> Table 'RAW_DATA' does not exist

the same code is working in Jupiter notebook but it doesn't work in vs code. My role is accountadmin so no issue with the permissions.

Code I am trying to run is this

```
COPY INTO RAW_DATA file_format=(FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are using a different Database/schema than the Jupiter notebook

```
select current_warehouse(), current_database(), current_schema();
```

for me gives:

| CURRENT_WAREHOUSE() | CURRENT_DATABASE() | CURRENT_SCHEMA() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COMPUTE_WH | TEST | TMP |

and your local will be somewhere different.

The simple way to fix this is to always use fully qualifed names. Thus for me:

```
COPY INTO test.tmp.raw_data file_format=(FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)
```

Comment: I tried this as well. But I am not sure maybe some string conversion or extra space was there. But after parametrizing the same thing it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 'TABLE' with your table name.

Example:

```
COPY INTO mytable FROM 's3://mybucket/./../a.csv';
```

Comment: here TABLE is my table name only and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error. You cannot name use `TABLE` as a table name. `TABLE` is a reserved keyword
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html

From the docs:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

```
COPY INTO [<namespace>.]<table_name>
     FROM { internalStage | externalStage | externalLocation }
[ FILES = ( '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ] ) ]
[ PATTERN = '<regex_pattern>' ]
[ FILE_FORMAT = ( { FORMAT_NAME = '[<namespace>.]<file_format_name>' |
                    TYPE = { CSV | JSON | AVRO | ORC | PARQUET | XML } [ formatTypeOptions ] } ) ]
[ copyOptions ]
[ VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_<n>_ROWS | RETURN_ERRORS | RETURN_ALL_ERRORS ]
```

So instead of

```
COPY INTO TABLE FILE_FORMAT = (FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)
```

try

```
 COPY INTO MYTABLE FILE_FORMAT = (FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)
```

Of course you will need to create `MYTABLE` first.

Comment: I am trying with ROW_DATA as my table name

Comment: Then `COPY INTO ROW_DATA FILE_FORMAT = (FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' SKIP_HEADER =1)`

Answer (score 1):

It was not working with

```
COPY INTO RAW_DATA file_format=(FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)
```

But Then I tried

```
table_name = "RAW_DATA"
f"COPY INTO {table_name} file_format=(FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' skip_header=1)"
```

it started working.
Not sure why but this seems working for now